# webpack plugin error on react-pdf installation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, react-pdf

I just installed react-pdf on a project, but the app crashes with the below error. Am I missing something here? Or do I need any config changes to webpack? Thanks

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'addFileToAssets' of undefined

  - addAllAssetsToCompilation.js:67 
    [thinking-nation-web]/[add-asset-html-webpack-plugin]/lib/addAllAssetsToCompilation.js:67:55

  - Generator.next

  - addAllAssetsToCompilation.js:101 step
    [thinking-nation-web]/[add-asset-html-webpack-plugin]/lib/addAllAssetsToCompilation.js:101:807

  - addAllAssetsToCompilation.js:101 
    [thinking-nation-web]/[add-asset-html-webpack-plugin]/lib/addAllAssetsToCompilation.js:101:1037

  - new Promise

  - addAllAssetsToCompilation.js:101 
    [thinking-nation-web]/[add-asset-html-webpack-plugin]/lib/addAllAssetsToCompilation.js:101:718

  - addAllAssetsToCompilation.js:98 addFileToAssets
    [thinking-nation-web]/[add-asset-html-webpack-plugin]/lib/addAllAssetsToCompilation.js:98:66

  - addAllAssetsToCompilation.js:105 
    [thinking-nation-web]/[add-asset-html-webpack-plugin]/lib/addAllAssetsToCompilation.js:105:11

  - index.js:4 pReduce
    [thinking-nation-web]/[p-each-series]/index.js:4:73

  - index.js:16 Promise.all.then.value
    [thinking-nation-web]/[p-reduce]/index.js:16:10

Html Webpack Plugin:
```

Comment: did you ever come up with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Version `"add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0"` - solved the issue for me.
You could also check that `DllReferencePlugin` and `HtmlWebpackPlugin` placed before this plugin